# Changing a component's public variable from sibling component

Tags: angular, typescript, public

I have two sibling components that are set from my `app.component`:

```
<my-a></my-a>
<my-b></my-b>
```

This visibility of `<my-a>` is controlled by a public variable in it's component:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-a',
  templateUrl: `<div *ngIf="visible">Hello World</div>`
})

export class MyAComponent {
    public visible = false;
}
```

I would like to change the value of `visible` after a click on an element in `<my-b>`:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-b',
  templateUrl: `<div (click)="onClick()">Click Me</div>`
})

export class MyBComponent {
    onClick() {
        // stuff here
    }
}
```

**How can I set `visible = true` in `<my-a>` from `<my-b>`?** Should the logic for this be in the parent `app.component`?

*EDIT*

Thanks for the answers. I implemented something in a couple lines of jQuery which works fine:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-b',
  templateUrl: `<div (click)="onClick('my-a')"></div>`
})

export class MyBComponent {
    onClick(element) {
        $(element).show(); // or hide() or toggle() or whatever
    }
}
```

Using jQuery makes it easily scalable if we want many more elements, instead of adding emitters and inputs to every component.

I'm just worried that using jQuery is bad practice in Angular2?

Comment: I am not too familiar with JQuery, but if I recall the selector is a CSS selector.  Angular2 will sometimes deform names/classes to create a 'shadow dom' to isolate components and prevent CSS from interfering with one another.  So using JQuery between components may be troublesome.  But take my warning with a light weight as I don't use it much.

Answer (score 2):

There's few ways to do that. IMO simpliest will be use of EventEmitter and Input.

Component A:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-a',
  templateUrl: `<div *ngIf="visible">Hello World</div>`
})

export class MyAComponent {
    // listen for variable passed by parent
    @Input() visible;
}
```

Component B:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-b',
  templateUrl: `<div (click)="onClick()">Click Me</div>`
})

export class MyBComponent {
    // creating EventEmitter to emit when onClick is called
    @Output() visible = new EventEmitter();
    onClick() {
        this.visible.emit();
    }
}
```

And in parent component:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'parent',
  // passing variable visible to MyAComponent and listening for (onClick) from MyBComponent
  templateUrl: `<my-a [visible]="visible"></my-a>
                <my-b (onClick)="changeVisible()"></my-b>`
})

export class ParentComponent{
    private visible: boolean = false;
    // when MyBComponent emits event change visible value (which is then passed to MyAComponent)
    changeVisible() {
    if (this.visible === false) {
    this.visible = true;
    } else {
        this.visible = false;
        }      
    }
}
```

In more advanced cases you should use shared service though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I believe it would work but I've updated my question with the solution I found, using jQuery. My solution works fine and is straightforward and scalable, I'm just worried it's bad practice?

Answer (score 1):

The logic is split into three parts, but yes, it centers around the parent app.component.  You think about it as specific tasks:

1. needs to give access to external sources to change visibility.  You will do this with an Input property
2. has a button, and the intent of this button is to trigger some action on a different component.  So it should have an Output property (which is an EventEmitter)
3. The parent object can then bind to 's Output to set a variable which it binds to 's Input.

## Input property in MyAComponent

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-a',
  template: `<div *ngIf="visible">Hello World</div>`
})
export class MyAComponent {
    @Input() visible: boolean = false;
}
```

The HTML that the parent component would use to set this would be:

```
<my-a [visible]="aVisibility"></my-a>
```

## Output property in MyBComponent

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-b',
  template: `<div (click)="onClick()">Click Me</div>`
})
export class MyBComponent {
    @Output() makeVisible: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();

    onClick() {
        this.makeVisible.emit();
    }
}
```

The HTML for the parent component that wants to listen to the change would be like this:

```
<my-b (makeVisible)="makeAVisible()"></myb>
```

## Using the parent to tie it together

```
import { component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: my-app,
    template: `
      <my-a [visible]="aVisibility"></my-a>
      <my-b (makeVisible)="makeAVisible()"></myb>
    `
})
export class MyApp {
    private aVisibility:boolean = false;

    makeAVisible() : void {
        this.aVisibility = true;
    }
}
```

## Notes

This is all untested code, so likely typos and errors.  Also, if the communication between the two components is complicated then you should prefer having a Service shared between the two, but for something simple like this, I think going through the parent is okay.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I believe it would work but I've updated my question with the solution I found, using jQuery. My solution works fine and is straightforward and scalable, I'm just worried it's bad practice?